# UILabel subclassing a subclass does not display

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm trying to create a custom `UILabel`, my first subclass is working as expected, i do some font attributes modifications and changes.

```
@IBDesignable class LunaLbl: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable dynamic open var fontSize: CGFloat = 25 {
        didSet {
            updateFont()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable dynamic open var fontName: String = Fonts.proDisplayBold.rawValue {
        didSet {
            updateFont()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable dynamic open var fontColor: UIColor = .lunaBlack {
        didSet {
            updateFont()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable dynamic open var lineSpacing:  CGFloat = 1.2 {
        didSet {
            updateFont()
        }
    }
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        updateFont()
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    }

    func updateFont() {
        let textContent = self.text
        let textString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textContent!, attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)!])
        let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: textString.length)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        textString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)
        textString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: fontColor, range: textRange)
        self.attributedText = textString
    }
}
```

Now my second subclass, that inherits from my first subclass has nothing  displayed on my screen.

```
@IBDesignable class LunaTitleLbl : LunaLbl {
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        fontSize = 25.0
        fontName = Fonts.proDisplayBold.rawValue
        fontColor = .lunaBlack
        updateFont()
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    }
}
```

I do the same thing, i inherits my new subclass from the storyboard directly, but nothing shown when I debug it using view hierarchy, my label was created and it takes the values I want, but the text is not shown.

Thats how i inherits my subclass 
[image]

Comment: You should not be overriding `draw` in the first place. You can put setup code into initializer or `awakeFromNib` instead.

Comment: @Sulthan i try it, but it does not work

Comment: Show how you create and configure the second one.

Comment: @matt i update mu question, i configure it from storyboard, i didnot use code.

Comment: So if the label is in the storyboard, run the app and use the View Debugger to see where it has gone. Look for exclamation marks telling you it has problematic constraints.

Comment: @matt, debug view hierarchy my label was at shown without text

Comment: When I change the attribute name lineSpacing and all things work as expected, I think the problem is that I'm using the same label attribute name.

Comment: Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change the attribute name **lineSpacing** and all things work as expected, I think the problem is that I'm using the same label attribute name.